# Register-WmiEvent Powershell script as a local GPO - Control USB

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

for many days I am fighting with a script that I would like to run in order to control when a user plugges a USB stick in the workstation.
This is a simplified version of the script.

```
Unregister-Event RemovableDiskDetection

$query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' AND TargetInstance.DriveType=2"
Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier RemovableDiskDetection -Action {
    $class = $eventArgs.NewEvent.__CLASS
    $device = $eventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.DeviceID
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    switch($class)
    {
        __InstanceCreationEvent {
            $path = $device + "\flag"
            Write-Host "*** Checking the existence of the file $path"
            if(Test-Path -Path $path)
            {           
                $wshell.Popup("Inserted, device id: $device WITH flag",0,"Done",0x1)
            }
            else{
                $wshell.Popup("Inserted, device id: $device WITHOUT flag",0,"Done",0x1)
            }
        }
        __InstanceDeletionEvent {
                $wshell.Popup("Removed, device id: $device ",0,"Done",0x1)
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the script from the Windows Powershell ISE it works as expected. If I open a CMD window and run the command "powershell -noexit -file basicUSBControl.ps1" , it also works as expected.

My issue is when I try to set the execution of this script for the whole computer affecting to any user who might log into the computer.
I tried via the Local Group Policy Editor. I went to the 
Computer Configuration-->Windows Settings--> Scripts --> Startup
Then I chose Powershell script tab and set the same script as before. I also chose the option in the drop down box " Run Windows Powershell scripts first".

Then I proceed to restart the computer and log into it and nothing seems to happen whenever I plug any USB stick.

Any idea what might be happening?Could anyone help me out? I am getting crazy and, maybe it is just not possible to do what I need to do....
I also tried with a scheduled task, the resulted task status shows "Running" all the time but not event is caught, not popups showns when plug and unplug usb sticks... :/

Many thanks!

Comment: Startup scripts are expected to run once and finish in a timely manner - if you check the system event log on your machine, you'll probably find that an error is logged regarding a startup or policy script that fails because it takes too long (10 minutes by default if memory serves me). Use a scheduled task than runs on startup/login instead

Comment: Hi Mathias, I tried with scheduled task and only when the task is run by the same user, the powershell actually works. I need to have  this hook active for any user who logs into the computer. if I even set it hidden, it doesnt work anymore... regarding the GPo solution, you said that every script via GPO has a timeout of 10 min. that means that the script should work for that period of time, and it doesnt work either...I dont know what else to try ...

Comment: after many tries, I found the solution which is not perfect but at least works.
You need to create the scheduled task via GPO. doing that way, you can set the user who run the script to 
%LogonDomain%\%LogonUser%

and set the task as hidden.

Comment: Cool! Post that as an answer!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  I tried to do so but I got the error "We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to create a GPO where the scheduled task is created.
there you can specify the user who will run the script, in my case,
%LogonDomain%\%LogonUser%